# Disable ONLY Chrome Automation Extension in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I've been researching this extensively but i have yet to even find a single topic about this specific question. I use python to access Selenium Webdriver, and have been disabling the extensions through python using the code

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
```

Recently though, i've wanted to load a custom profile, and that means custom extensions. is there a way to get rid of ONLY the automation extension?

[image]

ALSO, as a follow up curiosity, what even makes the chrome browser automatically start out with this extension loaded?

Thanks!

Comment: Patrick, this extension is what allows Selenium to hook into the driver. Disabling it would likely break Selenium's interface to the chromedriver

Comment: Damn, i was hoping that wasn't the case. I wonder if that's how companies like Distill Networks can automatically detect selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the Chrome Automation Extension by adding an experimental option to ChromeOptions like so:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
```